# Unknown Problem with Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

Im trying to use generic types for the first time in Java , as I only want my constructor to accept classes that implement the "Anealable" interface. theres a problem with my code by the only error I get is "Illegal start of Type" which is not getting very far with trying to make it work

here is the code for my class

```
package simulated_anealing;

public class Crystal extends Thread {

    Object a;

    public  Crystal(<? implements Anealable> a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gwilym - this comment is off-topic, but it is generally a bad idea to extend Thread.  It would probably be better to declare Crystal as implementing Runnable, and then run it using a separate Thread object.  That way you have the option of doing thread pooling, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just pass into the constructor the Anealable type like this :

```
package simulated_anealing;

public class Crystal extends Thread {

    Object a;

    public  Crystal(Anealable a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Will this mean that construtor will now accept only Classes that implement the Anealable interface?

Comment: ok just had a play with my code and this seems to work out. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to parameterize the class. If so then:

```
public class Crystal<T extends Anealable> extends Thread {
  Object a;

  public  Crystal(T a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, can parameterize methods (including constructors) like so:

```
public class Crystal extends Thread {
  public <T extends Anealable> Crystal(T t) {
    // do stuff with T
  }
}
```

It's hard to determine what your intent is so I can't really comment on which would suit your needs.

Comment: You *can* parameterize constructors too.